# How to paste data-frame directly to powerpoint using python-pptx module

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-pptx

I have a data-farme which looks like:

```
          yyyymm      A_growth         B_growth
         201911        NaN              NaN
         201912       -1.0             -3.0
         202001       14.0             20.0
         202002        7.0              9.0
         202003       -2.0            -14.0
         202004      -44.0            -44.0
         202005       20.0              6.0
         202006       24.0             27.0
         202007       -7.0             -1.0
```

I want to directly export it to power point at bottom right of slide as a small `table.`

One way is to `create table` and then use for loops to fill each cell in the table which is time consuming.

How can I use `python-pptx` module to directly export this table to power point.?

I am using `blank_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[6]`  layout 6.

Comment: If this is just a single table, you can export it to a CSV / Excel file and link your slide to the file. Going through `python-pptx` is only worth it if you have a lot of tables to export to PowerPoint

Comment: I have around 95 such slides and using for loop for each slide.

Comment: There is no faster way in `python-pptx`, but I can't imagine this taking more than a millisecond for each table. Why do you say it's time-consuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `add_table()` function:
(see [docs](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/table.html))

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hi': [1, 2, 3], 'there': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(4), Inches(1.5)
shape = slide.shapes.add_table(3, 3, x, y, cx, cy)
table = shape.table
cell = table.cell(1, 2)
cell.text = str(df.iloc[1][2])
```